# TestFlight provisioning profile not valid

Tags: ios, xamarin, testflight

I have submitted iOS app to TestFlight and when my internal testers try to download app it says the provisioning profile is invalid. I have verified that the provisioning profile is not invalid. Is there something else that could be causing this.

I am using Xamarin on windows. I was able to successfully submit a different app to TestFlight using same certificate and app id.

Basically what i am looking for is a way to troubleshoot this other than just looking at the status of profile on the app store.

Comment: So by identifier i mean Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. So same identifier, and Certificate. Only difference is profile. I don't have device to attempt to download myself but working on getting one.

Comment: Hi, if is a different app, you'd better use the different identifier, and Certificate to create different provisioning profile to publish.

Comment: That makes no sense. Certificate identifies mac. Identifier identifies person/team. Profile defines app

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want to know that whether the tester has installed the app before downloading the version of TestFlight? If so, suggest that install the previous version then install the test version to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So problem here was needed to use App Store distribution instead of ad-hoc which to me is confusing considering i only wanted app on TestFlight so hopefully this clears things up for someone else.